# Prevent indirect communication

Tags: ns-3

I have such network topology:

```
A--B--C
\____/
```

(A connected to B and C, B connected to C)

I'm using PointToPointChannel to connect these nodes. 
And I want that A node will not be able to communicate with C node via node B (only using direct link)
How can I prevent such communication?

Answer (score 0):

You need routing to do this, perhaps static routing.
Here some manual to do this : http://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.18/models/html/routing-overview.html
and example of routing : ns-3-folder/examples/routing